# in ubuntu, how to save automatically each terminal session (and delete old ones)

Tags: bash, ubuntu, console

I have not the commands I use to try to realize this, but I remember the main idea : in .bashrc, I added a find command (with parameters selecting files with a given extension and older than 15 days, and with the option -delete) having the purpose to delete old log files, and a second statement, script -a , which records the file for this session.

it was something like this:

```
find -name "*.logFile" -and -atime +15 -delete
script -a <filename>
```

I did not specify  because it involved the command date in order to generate an unique filename.

but the result of these 2 lines was a bug : when I opened the terminal, I had a file ganarated each seconds, and in the terminal window a repetition of same strings of characters (e.g. the terminal window is empty, if I hit the 'a' key then the window will be full of 'a').

apparently it seems the .bashrc is launched in a loop, but why, that's a mistery for me.

thanks for any help.

olivier

Comment: if you want to log what `find` did, then you should start your `script` FIRST. it can't reach back in time and see what `find` did...

Comment: I don't want to record the result of the find command, which is needed only to avoid too many old log files.

Comment: script does open a NEW shell to record, so if you have `script` in your bashrc, you'll just go into an infinite loop.

Comment: Why are you using `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile`?

Comment: this is because I found .bashrc in the ~ directory; but I will try with .bash_profile

Comment: with the code in .bash_profile it seems I have to enter "source .bash_profile" in order to log the text; that's not the expected behaviour.